Do I need to flush an OutputStream before closing it?
There are a few related questions, but none of them quite provides the answer.
I provide a Serializer object, and it has a method setOutputStream() allowing the user to supply a destination for the output. By default it follows the protocol that it the user supplies the output stream, the user takes responsibility for closing it. However, the Serializer also provides an option setCloseOnCompletion(boolean); if this is called, the Serializer should close the stream itself when it has finished writing. (The main reason for providing this option is that there are some cases where the stream can be closed much earlier this way, thereby releasing resources).
Of course, the Serializer has no knowledge of specific subclasses of OutputStream, so it needs to handle all possibilities.
My main question is, should we call stream.flush() before calling stream.close()?
I would have expected that stream.close() would automatically flush the stream if this is necessary, but there doesn't seem to be anything in the OutputStream contract that mandates this.
Secondly, if I do call stream.flush(), what should I do if it fails? Do I run the risk that it fails only because the stream is already closed, in which case I would ideally want to ignore the error? Is there any way of testing whether the stream is already closed before I attempt the flush()?
If I were designing this API today I would probably replace setCloseOnCompletion(boolean) with setCompletionAction(Action<OutputStream>) - but I'm not.

if it is a BufferedOutputStream or, more precisely, a FilterOutputStream it is indeed  documented: "Implementation Requirements: When not already closed, the close method of FilterOutputStream calls its flush method, and then calls the close method of its underlying output stream."

It's clearly documented that the close method of OutputStream does nothing.
Therefore, if the user of your API is providing their own OutputStream object, they may or may not have implemented close to perform a flush.  If you need the stream to be flushed, it's safest if you flush it yourself.
Similarly, there is no guarantee that calling flush on an already-closed stream would thrown an IOException.  Or that if an IOException is thrown, it's because the stream is already closed.  So you probably do NOT want to ignore the exception.

Generally, OutputStream decorators will extend FilterOutputStream, which does have such a requirement stated in their close() method.

So it sounds like setCloseOnCompletion should have been called setFlushAndCloseOnCompletion - but keep its name as it is, as long as it's documented that it will flush before closing.

"It's clearly documented that the close method of OutputStream does nothing." But this is presumably not true of subclasses, so I fail to see how that information is useful to me.

"Generally, OutputStream decorators will extend FilterOutputStream" But I can't assume that, so it doesn't help me.

My point is that since your setOutputStream method allows the user to pass any OutputStream they like (unless there's some restriction that you haven't told us about), you mustn't assume that the OutputStream that's passed in does the "flush on close" thing.
